# in host to device communication protocol, what does high and low mean?

Tags: protocol, ps2

I'm trying to learn about the PS/2 protocol from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1YSbLnm4_o&t=2s). At about 4:00 he talks about low and high values.

[image: screenshot from video]

This part is to let the host send data to the device but the clock should come from the device.

My question is what is zero, what is one and what is z (high impedance) in this context?

Meaning; when he says "high" or "release the clock" for example, does he mean one or Z? *(I'm thinking Z)*

Comment: @ThePhoton I know very well the difference between Z and 0. I'm asking about what he means by low and high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to watch a 16 minute video, but I do know the PS/2 interface.

It uses open collector (drain) outputs and pullups to +5V, so high-Z is the same as '1' and the same as +5.0V. Low is 0V.

The outputs can **only** pull down to 0V and are never 'driven' to +5V, rather an external pullup resistor pulls the output logic state up to +5 when the output goes high impedance. Picture below from [here](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2protocol/)

[image]

It's possible to simulate open-collector outputs with most micros by switching the port pin from an output with '0' state to an input, and never having it as an output with '1' state.

The distinction between 'release' and '1' is more of logical distinction than a description of what is happening in the hardware of the physical interface. When you want to transmit a '1' you allow it to go to high. When you are finished with sending data you 'release' it (allow it to go high) so that something else (the other end of the communication) can use it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "open-collector" circuits unfortunately. do you mean that high is 1 and Z at the same time?

Comment: ...so he uses "high" interchangeably between sending 1 and z?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Two (or more) outputs can use the same wire (one at a time, of course). The outputs that are not using the wire must allow it to go high (or be pulled low by some external influence).

Comment: @MinaMichael See my bottom paragraph above. It's sort of a (logical) distinction without a (physical) difference.

Answer (score 1):

By releasing the clock, he means that the pin for the shared clock line is placed in high impudence mode by the host. This means the host does not control or otherwise effect the line, letting the device take over.

Since this is an open collector protocol, 'high' really means the host or slave let go of the line, letting the external pull-up resistor take over. 'Low' means they actively pull the line to ground. At no point should the host or peripheral pull the line actively high through their own pins.

in essence 'high' and high-z are the same thing here. 0 and 1 still apply as low and high.

Comment: ...so he uses high sometimes to mean z and sometimes to mean 1?

Comment: In an open collector bus, they mean the same thing, kinda